# Passing array as argument in GraphQL

Tags: node.js, facebook, graphql

I have started working on [GraphQL](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/).My schema contains one list item too.

Following is the code of my schema:

```
var userType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({  
 name: 'user',
 fields: function () {
  return {
    _id: {
    type: graphql.GraphQLID
  },
  name: {
    type: graphql.GraphQLString
  },
  age: {
    type: graphql.GraphQLString
  },
  degrees:[
  {type:graphql.GraphQLList}
  ]
}
  }
   });
```

AND the query is as follows:

```
  var QueryType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({  
  name: 'Query',
  fields: () => ({
    userArr: {
      type: new graphql.GraphQLList(userType),
      args:{
         degrees:{type:new graphql.GraphQLList(userType)}
      },
     resolve: function(source, args) {
        console.log(args);
        resolve(args);
      }
    }
})
})
```

I got this error.
[image]

Basically i need to post the array from client graphql query and have to define query accordingly which i am unable to achieve.
Any suggestions because i can't find any help over this issue..

Answer (score 4):

`GraphQLObjectType` is not a valid input type.

See [Mutations and Input Types](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/mutations-and-input-types/)

"Input types can't have fields that are other objects, only basic scalar types, list types, and other input types."

You can use the suggestion above because `GraphQLString` is a scalar

```
degrees:{
    type:new graphql.GraphQLList(graphql.GraphQLString)
}
```

Otherwise, you would need to define a `GraphQLInputObjectType`

```
const userInputType = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
    name: 'userInput',
    fields: { /* put your fields here */ }
});
/* some code in between */

degrees:{
    type:new graphql.GraphQLList(userInputType)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I did something very similar recently. Your **input arguments** don't need to hold to the same type system as the when it's formatting the **output** data to send back. So your arg just needs to simply accept a list of strings or objects, or whatever standard type you want to send in.

In this case, I updated it to accept a list(array) of strings.

```
 var QueryType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({  
  name: 'Query',
  fields: () => ({
    userArr: {
      type: new graphql.GraphQLList(userType),
      args:{
         degrees:{type:new graphql.GraphQLList(graphql.GraphQLString)}
      },
     resolve: function(source, args) {
        console.log(args);
        resolve(args);
      }
    }
})
})
```

Also, I noticed on your user type, you have degrees surrounded with array brackets.
Similar to your degrees input argument, you'll be outputting an array of strings.
Try something like this:

```
  degrees:{
    type:new graphql.GraphQLList(graphql.GraphQLString)
  }
```

Happy coding!

Comment: I have tried this too now it is giving this error. **user.degrees field type must be Output Type but got: undefined.**

Comment: can u please confirm that the code in userType is correct or not?

Comment: Gotcha, could you post up your userType? just edit your original post and post a github gist code snippit if it's large

Comment: my question already contains the userType.u can see the first code block.

Comment: Wow, not sure how I missed that O_O. Anywho, I updated my answer, looks like you just needed to format things differently to handle lists. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Hi Justin, Can you please help me here ?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43337929/error-can-only-create-list-of-a-graphqltype-but-got-function-graphqlobjecttype